# is it possible to color one given line in console without writing text to it?

Tags: c++, windows, console

Normally this is done by `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` and then writting text. But it is possible to change line colors after text has been written to the line ?

Answer (score 3):

At least if memory serves, [`WriteConsoleOutputAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687407.aspx) can do that.

Edit: ...or, if you want a block all set to the same attribute, you can use [`FillConsoleOutputAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682662.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can set the cursor back up to that line, change color, rewrite the text, then jump back to where the cursor was before the jump to rewrite.

I'm not an expert c++ programmer (despite wearing my "Hello World!" t shirt today ☺), so I can't give you any help...

Comment: `ReadConsoleOutputAttribute` lets you read what's already on the screen.